# Why isn't my acer computer working?

Tags: acer-revo

My computer will only work when it is plugged in but the only way you can see the screen is when you a hold a flashlight to it when it is plugged in? Its an acer chromebook

Comment: It could be a few things. Likely the backlight on your display has gone bad.

Answer (score 3):

> the only way you can see the screen is when you a hold a flashlight to it when it is plugged in?

LCD screens in laptops have a component called an *inverter* that provides power to the screen and its backlight.  It's possible this has gone out.  A computer repair shop can get another one from eBay or other sources and replace it for you.

If your system is under warranty and has no signs of physical damage, contact the manufacturer to fix.